# What are the first version numbers of each major browser that fully supports Blazor Webassembly 6.0?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, browser-support

I am trying to find what is the first version number of each major brower that supports Blazor webassembly.

The MS documentation is not specific as it only indicates that the latest version is supported
[Here is the MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Regarding this question I found a matrice about webassembly compatibility here on the [dev mozilla web site](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebAssembly#browser_compatibility) but I failed to interprate it. Here is a small part of the matrice :
[image]

Please could you tell me which line of the matrice may show the first browser version number compatible with Blazor Webassembly ? Or if it is not as simple as that, please could you give me a few hints to better understand ?

Thank you very meuch in advance

Comment: Blazor only need WebAssembly (1.0), meaning support started ~2017 (way before Blazor itself).

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman, thank you very much for your answers.  My users are in Africa (Ivory Coast, Senegal, Cameroun, Gabon ... ) And by looking at their users agent I notice that a part of them uses old browser versions. Mainly on old Android phones.  That is why I am doing these research.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think i will check what is the portion whith browser versions released before mid 2017. it will give me a good approximate about the % of my users that are not eligible to navigate a Blazor website. Thanks again for your answers  :-)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=wasm) can add some detail.